# Get unique list of files in a directory that do *not* contain a line

Tags: awk, grep

Say I have a project with a bunch of .js files. I want to find out which files do not contain this line:

```
const process = require('suman-browser-polyfills/modules/process');
```

If I do

`grep -v "suman-browser-polyfills/modules/process" .`

then it will simply log every line of every file that does not match.
That's not going to give me what I want at all.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: `-L, --files-without-match` *Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input file from which no output would normally have been printed.*

Comment: thanks, `-L` is alias for `--files-without-match`?

Comment: @steeldriver You should make this an answer because otherwise is looks like this question had not been answered yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-L` option (or its long option equivalent, `--files-without-match`

From the *General Output Control* section of `man grep`:

```
 -L, --files-without-match
       Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input
       file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The
       scanning will stop on the first match.
```

So for example,

```
 grep -FL "const process = require('suman-browser-polyfills/modules/process');" *.js
```

(the `-F` option tells grep to treat the search pattern as a fixed string, rather than a regular expression - there don't appear to be any regex-special characters in your example pattern, but we shouldn't assume that will always be the case.)

Comment: thanks nice answer, at first I thought I needed the `grep -v` option, but you demonstrated that I don't want that.